# What is "we" (speaker and listener) in Japanese?

Tags: english-to-japanese, pronouns

How do you say "we" (as in the speaker and listener) in Japanese?

Comment: English does not have a specific word for this either; the distinction between 'inclusive' and 'exclusive' we is not universal

Answer (score 4):

Like English and many other languages, Japanese does not differentiate between the "we" that includes the listener, and the "we" that excludes the listener. If you're looking for the general translation for the word "we", then depending on the formality, there are many options, such as 私たち、僕たち、僕ら, etc., and it's quite difficult to even give a exhaustive list. **Note that none of these imply whether the listener is included or excluded.** You may want to refer to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_pronouns#List_of_Japanese_personal_pronouns) for more details. Look for the header "we". This is the general answer for "how to say we in Japanese"

When the "we" refers to an organization/company, though, the words used are yet again different. A school can refer to themselves as 本校/当校 in their official communications, a store can be 本店/当店/弊店, a company can be 本社, 当社 or 弊社. The 本 literally means "this", and 弊 literally means insignificant. It's used as a humble language.

> **We** are closed on Monday.
> **当店**は月曜日は休業しております。

If you're speaking as a representative of the company that you work for, you could use うち as "we" as in "our company":

> We(my workplace) are hiring, wanna come?
> **うち**はバイトを募集中なんだよ、来ないか？

It is also noteworthy that Japanese has a habit of omitting pronouns where possible, so if context is clear enough, not just "we", but all other already implied pronouns are dropped and understood. In those cases, the "we" is not spoken at all.